# Fake users signing up with @privaterelay.appleid.com accounts

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I have a firebase project. The following sign-up/sign-in methods are enabled:

- Google
- Apple

Every so often (once or twice a week -- not aligned with any App Reviews), I get a new user sign up with a @privaterelay.appleid.com account. Now what I don't understand is that I have session replays enabled, so I should be able to see any interaction a new user has. However, these signed up users never appear in my session replays.

How could someone sign up without interacting with my app (which would then appear in the session replays)? Also, why are these sign ups even happening (they're clearly not doing anything on the app)?